# Is there a way to make a private connection between a Heroku Private Space and AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, heroku, amazon-s3

Is there a way to access S3 privately (not over the internet) from a Heroku Private Space?

Using Private Space Peering and a HTTP proxy is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku Private Spaces are connected to AWS S3 via AWS PrivateLink. As such, the connection to AWS S3 is private (not over the internet).

To whitelist a Heroku private space in an AWS S3 bucket policy, whitelist the Private Space's AWS VPC id. The VPC id can be found with the command `heroku spaces:peering:info --space <your space's name>`. Here is an example bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "example-policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowHerokuPrivateSpaceVpcAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "<your space's VPC id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Requests to the bucket will be logged as coming from private IPs (e.g. `10.0.0.0/16`).

Source: Heroku Support. This behavior is not documented in the Heroku documentation.

Comment: This looks like useful information. However, the question doesn't appear to be an actual programming question. Thus, it is probably more appropriate for [su], [sf], or some other Stack Exchange site. If you do post it elsewhere, please be sure to read that site's on-topic page prior to posting.